# symfony 4 controller does not return any response anymore

Tags: symfony

Everything worked fine yesterday. I power off the development server then power on this morning and now I am only getting the following error message no matter what I do.

All I did was go to bed.... I tried changing route, deleting the return and recreating it, nothing fixes it.

`The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?`

here is my controller:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/blog/list", name="blogList", methods={"POST"})
 * @param Request $args
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */

function blogListing(Request $args) {

   $A = $args->request->get('a');

    return $this->render('listings/blogListing.html.twig',[
        'args' => $A
    ]);
}
```

symfony error window:

```
Kernel->handle(object(Request))
in public/index.php (line 40)
Request::setTrustedHosts(explode(',', $trustedHosts));}$kernel = new Kernel($env, $debug);$request = Request::createFromGlobals();$response = $kernel->handle($request);$response->send();$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug...

I changed my controller name from `blogListing` to `blogList` and it worked fine... I miss no framework days..

Comment: Perhaps you should try a different bed?